# Using java code how to connect sharePoint site

Tags: java, sharepoint

I need to connect **http://********.com/sites/sm01/fc/SMDL/Forms/AllItems.aspx**
after that I need upload files using java code.
Help me on same.

I used org.apache.httpcomponents API but not success. I got bellow error

14:46:41.124 [main] WARN  o.a.h.i.a.HttpAuthenticator - NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
error